# Implemantations of Java EE API and application server

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, wildfly

I would like to know if there is some pages or documents where there is all the API (and versions of the API if possible) that implements the JavaEE7 specifications for WildFly-8 and for GlassFish-4 application servers

such as http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html for TomEE

TomEE

The Web Profile version of TomEE contains

CDI - Apache OpenWebBeans

EJB - Apache OpenEJB

JPA - Apache OpenJPA

JSF - Apache MyFaces

JSP - Apache Tomcat

JSTL - Apache Tomcat

JTA - Apache Geronimo Transaction

Servlet - Apache Tomcat

Javamail - Apache Geronimo JavaMail

Bean Validation - Apache BVal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a table with **Java EE Standards Implementations in GlassFish Server 4.0** in the [GlassFish 4.0 Release Notes](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/release-notes.pdf), but this shows basically the versions of the specific standards which are implemented. As GlassFish 4 is the Java EE 7 reference implementation, it contains basically implementations of APIs which are part of Java EE 7.

This [blog post by Arun Gupta](http://blog.arungupta.me/2013/10/java-ee-7-implementations-in-wildfly-tech-tip-3/) contains detailed information about the implementation versions of the different APIs in Wildfly 8.

But what you really want is [this blog post by Arjan Tijms](http://arjan-tijms.blogspot.de/2014/05/implementation-components-used-by.html). It has an detailed overview over the implementation versions which are used in the most popular application servers.